# How increase the font size of an equation with begin{equation}?

Tags: equations, fontsize, rmarkdown

I have the following code in **RMarkdown** that prints an equation like:

```
# in a LaTeX environment I would write:

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq: eq1}
\psi_{j} = \frac{\gamma_{i,j,k}^s}{\sqrt{w_{i,j,n}}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Yet, I would like to increase the font size of the equation. All I found online doesn't work. Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: What  do you mean? Having a bigger font size in equations?

Comment: @Bernard exactly

Comment: put `\large` before the `\begin` or `\Large` or `\huge`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle it makes all that comes after the equation also bigger, is there a way to limit it only to the equation?

Comment: put it in a group, or put `\normalsize` after `\end{equation}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks a lot!